# Call block function from within controller in Magento

Tags: magento

How can i call the block function from the controller in the Magento.

I have the bellow controller:

Mage/checkout/controllers/CartController.php

I want to call the bellow block function in this CartController

Mage/checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php

How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You may use:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_shipping');
```

to get the block.

Answer (score 6):

Hi you can call block in controller by two ways, check below:

```
 $myblock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('checkout/cart_shipping')->getYourfunctionname();
```

OR

```
$myblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_shipping')->getYourfunctionname();
```

Answer (score 1):

Load your block in your controller

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','checkout')->setTemplate('checkout/cart1.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create simple getTest() function in Mage/checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php like this.

```
public function getTest()
{
     $data = 'test';
     return $data;
}
```

And call it in Mage/checkout/controllers/CartController.php file like this.

```
echo $this->getTest();
```